# How to programmatically add HTML DOM breakpoints in chromium?

Tags: javascript

I've seen from [this post about Chromium DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#dom) that there exists the possibility to add DOM breakpoints. Given that I've a full range of elements to monitor I was trying to find a way to programmatically add such breakpoints.

To achieve a similar result I've used to instrument the `setAttribute()` function of such DOM elements replacing it with a wrapper that uses the `debugger;` instruction to trigger the debugger. Anyway this approach fails when dealing with innerHTML or innerText assignments given that there is no way of achieving operator overloading in js.

Can someone suggest me a practical solution?